Why is acpi-daemon disabled?
Why is acpid disabled on my machine. I am sure that I never explicitly disabled it. Why is it disabled, although the vendor preset is enabled?
❯ systemctl status acpid


● acpid.service - ACPI event daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/acpid.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-04-02 09:46:51 CEST; 2h 13min ago
TriggeredBy: ● acpid.socket
             ● acpid.path
       Docs: man:acpid(8)
   Main PID: 1968 (acpid)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38077)
     Memory: 484.0K
        CPU: 3.970s
     CGroup: /system.slice/acpid.service
             └─1968 /usr/sbin/acpid

Apr 02 09:46:51 p15 systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Apr 02 09:46:52 p15 acpid[1968]: starting up with netlink and the input layer
Apr 02 09:46:52 p15 acpid[1968]: 8 rules loaded
Apr 02 09:46:52 p15 acpid[1968]: waiting for events: event logging is off
Apr 02 09:48:52 p15 acpid[1968]: input device has been disconnected, fd 17

